# How to load data from HTTPPOST request in server side?

Tags: c#, wcf, post, uri, webinvoke

I have a WebInvoke method like this;

```
[OperationContract]

    [WebInvoke(

        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/go",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml

    )]       
    string go(string name);
```

and I post the data like this;

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        string reply = client.UploadString(
            "http://localhost/HelloService/Service.svc/go",
            "POST",
            aString);
```

The question is how can I take the data from posted message in **go()** method without using a uri template like this;

```
UriTemplate = "/go({name})"
```

Because I want to sent large amount of data and I cannot sent it in uri template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution;

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
Method = "POST",
UriTemplate="/go"
)]  
string MyWebServiceMethod(string name);
```

and HTTP POST request is;

```
POST /go Modify HTTPS/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: WebserviceURL
Content-Length: length

{"name":"someName"}
```

Comment: It is not quite obvious what the change was, in order to make the answer more useful, can you please elaborate on the solution a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`?

You could try System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form, or, it looks like you are using XML for your request format, so you may want to try loading an XElement or XmlDocument from the request stream.

(may have the wrong method here, but it exists somewhere in the request object)
// .NET 4.0 only

```
XElement el = XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetRequestStream());
```

Comment: I cannot access to System.Web.HttpContext.Current. Do I need.Net4.0?